# Connection to Tomcat JMX server failing

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, jmx

Failing to connect to Tomcat JMX instance

Ok i am stuck now - Im trying to configure JMX with Tomcat as follows

`$CATALINA_BASE/setenv.sh`:

```
CATALINA_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=18070 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=$CATALINA_BASE/conf/jmxremote.password -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file=$CATALINA_BASE/conf/jmxremote.access"
export CATALINA_OPTS
```

`$CATALINA_BASE/conf/jmxremote.password`

```
    monitorRole monitorpass
    controlRole controlpass
```

`$CATALINA_BASE/conf/jmxremote.access`

```
    monitorRole readonly
    controlRole readwrite
```

The client tool i am using to access the Tomcat JMX server is running on the same machine as the Tomcat instance. when i start tomcat i can see that there is something listening at port 18070 but when i try to connect i get the following error

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: Authentication failed! Credentials required
            at com.sun.jmx.remote.security.JMXPluggableAuthenticator.authenticationFailure(JMXPluggableAuthenticator.java:193)
            at com.sun.jmx.remote.security.JMXPluggableAuthenticator.authenticate(JMXPluggableAuthenticator.java:145)
            at sun.management.jmxremote.ConnectorBootstrap$AccessFileCheckerAuthenticator.authenticate(ConnectorBootstrap.java:185)
            at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIServerImpl.doNewClient(RMIServerImpl.java:213)
```

I connect using the following bit of code

```
            try {
                url = new JMXServiceURL("service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:18070/jmxrmi");
                jmxc = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(url,null); 
                mbsc = jmxc.getMBeanServerConnection();             
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                throw new Exception(methodName + ":" + e);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new Exception(methodName + ":" + "Failed to connect to the Tomcat Server " + e);
            }
```

It works fine if i set com.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=true to false. Other than that it just fails. The client tool is running on the same machine as the tomcat instance so there should not be any issues with the firewall. Any clues

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This

```
JMXServiceURL url = ...;
Map env = ...;
String[] creds = {"monitorRole", "mrpasswd"};
env.put(JMXConnector.CREDENTIALS, creds);
JMXConnector cc = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(url, env);
MBeanServerConnection mbsc = cc.getMBeanServerConnection();
```

from http://blogs.oracle.com/lmalventosa/entry/jmx_authentication_authorization

should help

Comment: Oh i didnt know that i had to provide the credentials from the client side. I thought Tomcat would read them from the password file. i will try the above example thanks.

Comment: But that's the threat - a client that can read and manipulate the VM should be authorized to do so.